# Subtracting first value from next value based on ID

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm using R and I have a data frame called "g1" which contains tumor volumes in mice, which all have an ID.  This study is over many weeks and during this period mice are removed from the trial.  I want to calculate a relative tumor volume for each mouse, based on ID, by subtracting the day 0 value from the subsequent day's value and cannot seem to come up with a good way to do this.  For example I have

```
Mouse      Volume     Day
  711    7.323704       0
  712   39.751250       0
  713   22.568248       0
  714  120.376612       0
  706   85.169190       0
  707   29.695617       0
  708   65.026840       0
  709   33.697400       0
  711   44.380412       7
  712   49.326144       7
  713   30.275336       7
  714  136.680960       7
  709   41.739454       7
```

Mice 706, 707, 709, were taken out of the study (this happens continually). I would like to create a column called "RelVol" that is (day 7 volume -  day 0 volume) and (day 14 volume - day 0 volume) and so on and and so on until the end of my df.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work for you.

Using the `data.table` package

You can convert a data.frame to a data.table very easily:

```
 df <- data.table(OriginalDataFrame)
```

then use:

```
 df[, RelVol:= c(Volume - Volume[1]), by = Mouse]
```

where df is your data.table of values.

You'll get a new column created with the difference to day 0 per mouse at each 'Day'

:)

Comment: Perfect solution.  Thanks @Danny